# Monitoring android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, monitoring

I have designed an android application which is perfectly cool and it's working well. but I feel it's using System badly, Because i have written complicated codes.

I was wondering if i can monitor my application. For example see how much RAM, Network, CPU is using and how fast my app is.

Comment: At the bottom of Android Studio (at least in the newer versions), click the `Android Monitor` tab, then `Monitors`

Comment: ok my allocated memory is 35mb, u think its much? @AndrewBrooke

Comment: @AliMohamadi it depends. There is no "right memory usage". Moreover it depends on free memory and total amount of memory. On some device 35mb is ok, on others not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use Android Monitor in Android Studio.